# FPDF, Yii and jQuery not working

Tags: php, jquery, yii, fpdf

I'm using jQuery to post data to a Yii controller action that'll render a pdf. But facing some issues.

```
nom = "toto";
$.post(baseUrl+'print/recufrais',{"NomFichier" : nom+'.pdf', "id": code},
    function(responde)
    {
        console.log(responde);
    }
);
```

And the log is :

> %PDF-1.3
>       3 0 obj
>       <>
>       endobj
>       4 0 obj
>       <>
>       stream
>       x�e�MN�0��=���b<Ώ���dZ�� �@BlXq-��-�S$�"y��͛7
>       trailer
>       <<
>       /Size 9
>       /Root 8 0 R
>       /Info 7 0 R
>   >
>       startxref
>       987
>       %%EOF

The action is as follows :

```
public function actionRecufrais()
{
    //header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    $NomFichier = $_POST['NomFichier'];
    $PDF=New phpToPDF();
    $PDF->FPDF('P');
    $PDF->AddPage();

    $PDF->SetFont('Courier','B','15');//$PDF->SetXY(60, 47);
    $PDF->Ln(); 

    $PDF->MultiCell(0, 15, iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1252", "RECU DE REGLEMENT"), 0, "C", 0);

    $PDF->SetFont('Courier', 'B', '11');
    $PDF->MultiCell(0, 15, iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1252", "NOM ET PRENOMS DE L'ELEVE : "), 0, 'L', 0);


    $PDF->Output($NomFichier, 'F');
    $PDF->Output($NomFichier, 'D');
}
```

Is there something going wrong with my code ?

Comment: Did you try your code without ajax.. Is this working or not ??

Comment: I tried with GET (with the url http://localhost/app/index.php/print/recufrais/NomFichier/test.pdf) and everything is going well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh no. A dependence is missing : 

`require_once 'tools/php/functions.php';
$NomFichier = "etats/recufrais/" .$_POST['NomFichier'];`

inside my controller action. Thanks for your attention.